# How to organize articles on a 2D map based on their meaning?

Tags: objective-c, neural-network, nlp

I have saved locally on disk the first paragraph of every article in the English version of Wikipedia (6,000,000 total).

How can I make a 2D map where similar articles are close to each other while dissimilar articles are proportionally distant?

For example, think of the map as a 256x256 grid with 65,536 cells.

The article about "[canis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canis)" which is a breed of dogs is located in the cell at (356,39) along with other articles like the one for "[chihuahua](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chihuahua_(dog))", articles for some breeds of cats might be at (350,31) which is close while articles for "[aerospace engineering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aerospace_engineering)" and "[computer programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_programming)" are on the opposite site of the map.

Comment: What is the guy that you so-call a 2D map and which development are you referring to?

Comment: Is this a question about programming or about [statistics, machine learning, data analysis, data mining, and data visualization](https://stats.stackexchange.com/)?